# Override aui css of Liferay by Boostrap 3 css

Tags: css, overriding, liferay-aui

I'm using Boostrap 3 to create my website, i have override it css with my own - that part is easy. But when my partner use my design with Liferay 6.2, i realize boostrap css being override by aui.css =(( 
So how to make Boostrap css override (or have higher priority than aui.css)?
P/S: Have read somewhere about using liferay Hook but also it have a warning *"This should not follow because disable important liferay feature"* so how i do it safely without the risk of the warning or it the only way?

Comment: Liferay relies on Bootstrap 2.3.2, so I don't think there's any way to use Bootstrap 3 in Liferay due to conflicts. http://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/the-nitty-gritty-theme-improvements-and-bootstrap-in-liferay-6-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after hours search and tests i have find a way to apply bootstrap 3 css to liferay 6.2 (it work well now but if any error happen in the future i will edit this answer later) - in the _diffs/css have file name aui.css, open it and clear all contents inside it (save a back up before do this if you feel worry) and deploy again to see result.